# Reverse the order of the elements of an array of 32-bit integers

Tags: c, arrays

I have this task:

```
Reverse the order of an array of 32-bit integers
```

So, I have this array:

```
 { 0x12345678, 0xdeadbeef, 0xf00df00d };
```

It should look like this:

```
{ 0xf00df00d, 0xdeadbeef, 0x12345678 };
```

I've tried this, but with no success:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void reverse_array ( uint32_t *array, unsigned int count ) {
    uint32_t array[3] = {0x12345678, 0xdeadbeef, 0xf00df00d };
    reverse_array ( array, 3);
}
```

But it throws me:

```
main.c: In function ‘reverse_array’:
main.c:12:10: error: ‘array’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
uint32_t array[3] = {0x12345678, 0xdeadbeef, 0xf00df00d };
         ^~~~~
main.c:11:32: note: previous definition of ‘array’ was here
void reverse_array ( uint32_t *array, unsigned int count ) {
                               ^~~~~
```

Comment: For one thing, you need a [`int main()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) function and put `reverse_array ( array, 3);` in it.

Comment: The error tells you that you are declaring two different variables with the same name. In this case, you should just remove the second definition. Or more likely move it to `main()`.

Comment: Also, note that you are making a recursive call to reverse_array(...) from within reverse_array(...).

Comment: You have a recursive function that does not reverse anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message tells you that you are declaring two different variables with the same name:

```
void reverse_array ( uint32_t *array, unsigned int count )
```

Here you declare a parameter with the name `array`.

```
    uint32_t array[3] = {0x12345678, 0xdeadbeef, 0xf00df00d };
```

And here you declare a local variable with the same name.

The problem is that you put the code that should be in your `main()` function inside of `reverse_array()`. So your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void reverse_array ( uint32_t *array, unsigned int count ) {
   // You need to figure out what code to put here
}

void main() {
    uint32_t array[3] = {0x12345678, 0xdeadbeef, 0xf00df00d };
    reverse_array ( array, 3);
}
```

Now you need to figure out how to actually reverse the array.

Comment: ....and as `reverse_array ` doesn't do anything, there is just an infinite recursion. I wait for the question "Why do I get a segmentation fault?" (i.e. a stack overflow).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Good point. It appears that the OP put code inside of the `reverse_array()` function that belongs in `main()`. I edited my question to address this issue.